# Rails model specific Date formating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, number-formatting, activemodel

I have two models namely **post** and **comment**. Each model have a field named **created_at** with data type **date**, while rendering the json response i need to format the created_at field but it is different for both models.

for the model Post the format must be **May 12 2016**

for the comment model format is **05-12-2016**

is there any options for specifying the format with specific to model ?

And I don't want to have additional function because i have used to display date in different places, so if i write a function i need to change it in all places.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the JSON to contain ISO8601 time and date formats and then the consumer can decide how to display them? Pushing formatting issues to the very edges is generally the best approach.

Comment: @muistooshort i don't want consumer to hold the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions directly in your models to return the datetime of `created_at` at your whim.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_date
    created_at.strftime("%b %-d %y")
  end
end
```

and

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   def get_date
     created_at.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
   end
 end
```

then just put the following in your view:

```
<%= @comment.get_date %>
```

For more ways to format your datetime using the `strftime` method, check this out: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

**UPDATE (question now reflects the need for JSON)**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options)
     super(options).merge({
       :created_at => self.created_at.strftime("%b %-d %y")
     })
  end
end
```

and

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   def as_json(options)
     super(options).merge({
       :created_at => self.created_at.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
     })
   end
 end
```

Comment: I don't want to have additional function because i have used to display date in different places, so if i write a function i need to change it in all places.

Comment: The last two code blocks (after the update) only affect the JSON objects when using the `as_json` method. You don't have to use any of the others for that to work.

Comment: This will work fine if i am using as_json, but what if i don't use as_json.

Comment: What would you use besides as_json?

Comment: I have an scenario, when some users make comments on posts i need to send a mail. In the mail view file named **notification.html.rb** i am using `someone has commented on your post dated <%@post.created_at%>`

Comment: But in that instance, that's not JSON yet. It's going to print the content based on the Ruby. You can either use the top code block in this answer and use `<%= @post.get_date %>` or use `<%= @post.created_at.strftime("%b %-d %Y") %>` or assign `@post = Post.find(params[:id]).as_json` before passing it along. There's probably more possibilities than those 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117039/discussion-between-bala-karthik-and-okomikeruko).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `I18n` which is automatically provided with rails.

To set the format go to the `config/locales/<current_locale>.yml` (current_locale defaults to `en`).

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%b %-d %y"
      short: "%m-%d-%Y"
```

in your view you can then use it like this:

```
<p><%= I18n.l @post.created_at, format: :default %></p>
<p><%= I18n.l @comment.created_at, format: :short %></p>
```

Or if you want for the dirty, unofficial way, you can overwrite your getter in the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at
    I18n.l(super)    
  end
end
```

**NOTE** this is really nasty because you overwrite the getter of created_at. As it is a date, you can no longer the the real Date/Time object. Instead you will get a String everytime.

please use I18n! It's an good way to format the dates in rails.

Comment: Its one of the way to format, but is there any options to set default format for the attribute in model the model